# react navigator react-native-sectioned-multi-select how to convert into array items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to use `react-native-sectioned-multi-select` and I understand that the array must have name and id on it. So I was trying to fetch my data from url and store it as array but the drop down list won't show anything but loading circle.

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Body, Header, Title, Content, List, ListItem, Text, Left, Right, Icon, Footer, FooterTab, Button} from 'native-base';
import SectionedMultiSelect from 'react-native-sectioned-multi-select';

var items = [];

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      selectedItems: []
    };
  }

  getData(){
    return fetch('https://test.com/php.php')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(responseJson.result));
        this.setState({data:responseJson.result});
        //alert(responseJson.result[1].name);
        //return responseJson.result[1].name;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getData();

    this.state.data.map((cardData, i) =>{
        items.push({
              name: cardData.name,
              id: cardData.ver
        });
    });

  }
onSelectedItemsChange = selectedItems => {
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View>

        <SectionedMultiSelect
          items={items} 
          uniqueKey='id'
          selectText='Choose some things...'
          showDropDowns={false}
          readOnlyHeadings={false}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my code above, I am not sure how to push the array into my new items array correctly in order to make the list work.

data format should be only

```
result [{
   name: xxxxxx,
   ver: xxxxx
}]
```

Comment: possible anyone can help me in this?

Answer (score -1):

Here in your `items` you should be sending `this.state.data` and it should work:

```
<SectionedMultiSelect
    items={this.state.data} /* ** Here ** */ 
    uniqueKey='id'
    selectText='Choose some things...'
    showDropDowns={false}
    readOnlyHeadings={false}
     onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
     selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
 />
```

Comment: no is not working because it needs an id for unique key. in this case, my data array does not have them and i need to push it into another new array for this with name and id

Comment: What is the format of your `data`? I mean if you can give me a dummy data set for that `data` variable.

Comment: Ya I saw that. I tried to run react-native-sectioned-multi-select so that I can figure out something, but there is a problem with latest version of react-native. So I am unable to use this component in my laptop. Anyhow I will try soon to fix that problem and find a solution for your question.

Comment: i used the lower version of react native and latest ones is not useable for some reason. get the lower version of react native lole .54 i think